# Write bubble sort more concise way?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, functional-programming

is there some more concise way to write array sorting method by elements size using bubble sort algorithm implementation ? I'm not looking for a speed optimization neither, just for a more compact code, functional style preferred.

```
def sort_by_size(arr)
  # bubble sort
  (arr.length - 1).downto 1 do
    |ix|
    arr = arr[1..ix].inject([[],arr[0]]) {|(ac,g),e| g.size < e.size ? [ac << g, e] : [ac << e, g]}.flatten.concat(arr[ix+1..-1])
  end
  arr
end
```

Any idea ?

Comment: This belongs on CodeReview.SE.

Comment: Any particular reason to reinvent the wheel or just curiosity? `Array.sort`

Comment: I am all for functional programming, but bubble sort is inherently imperative (swaps all over the place), if you try a pure functional implementation you'll need to create a new array on each swapping; "terrible" is just an euphemism for the performance you'll get.

Comment: @nicooga Just a curiosity. I implemented this algorithm in haskell first and would like to compare it with a ruby version. Just asked if ruby can do better,  ie. more elegent/concise way then my attempt.

Comment: `loop until arr.each_cons(2).with_index.none?{|(x,y),i| ar[i],ar[i+1] = ar[i+1],ar[i] if y < x}`

Comment: @steenslag nice, inspirative. I had to upvote your comment, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
def sort_by_size!(a)
  loop do
    swapped = false

    a.size.times do |n|
      if a[n].size < a[n-1].size
        a[n], a[n-1] = a[n-1], a[n]
        swapped = true
      end unless n == 0
    end

    break unless swapped
  end

  array
end
```

The main approach is readability here. `array.sort_by! { |e| e.size }` or even `array.sort!`(most of the time) does the same job. If you are concerned about performance(or if you aren't) there are some benchmarks:

```
n = 100_000

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report('my bubble sort')    { n.times { sort_by_size! array.dup           } }
  x.report('your bubble sort')  { n.times { sort_by_size array.dup            } }
  x.report('sort_by!')          { n.times { array.dup.sort_by! { |e| e.size } } }
  x.report('sort')              { n.times { array.dup.sort!                   } }
end

                         user     system      total        real
my bubble sort       0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.196077)
your bubble sort     0.520000   0.000000   0.520000 (  0.524635)
sort_by!             0.090000   0.000000   0.090000 (  0.092452)
sort                 0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.024854)
```

I think the core ruby sorting methods win over my custom bubble sort both in readability and performance.

Comment: Thx for the reply although it does not directly answers my question. I just tried to find some more concise/compact way to write bubble-sort in ruby even not too efficient performance wise. Something such elegant as haskell's generic `bubbleSort :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
bubbleSort _ [] = []
bubbleSort p (x:xs) = step $ foldl' go (x,[]) xs
    where
    go (y,acc) x
        | p x y == LT = (x, y : acc)
        | otherwise = (y, x : acc)
    step (x,acc) = x : bubbleSort p acc` but it can not be probably done in ruby.

Comment: If you ask for a concise/compact ruby implementation of the [bubble sort algorythm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), that's what I gave you.